# How to use join to get data from one row?

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables let it be like follows:

**Table1**

```
  id     name      address   phone
   1     Nirdosh   Shrestha  984901
   2     krishna   hora      984902
   7     birami    pokhara   984903
```

**Table2**

```
  id     weight   destination  age
   1     52       balkhu       32
   2     53       hanger       35
   2     65       fursad       35
   3     70       Ktm          10
```

I want the result table like this:

**EXPECTED RESULT TABLE**

```
 id     name      address   phone  id  weight  destination  age
  1     Nirdosh   Shrestha  984901  1   52       balkhu       32
  2     krishna   hora      984902  2   53       hanger       35
  2     krishna   hora      984902  2   65       fursad       35
```

I tried and sql query is:

```
select table1.*,table2.*
from table1 LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id;
```

But my query do not give expected result.

Comment: Aside from being unoriginal, 'It is not working' is not a particularly useful explanation of a problem. However, if you don't want 7 or 3, then that's an INNER JOIN.

Comment: Yeah and you obviously got some sort of output, should have listed what it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, 'Not working' is not very clear. By your sample I guess you want to keep only those records that matches?

In this case it should be an `INNER JOIN` :

```
select t1.*,t2.*
from table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
 ON table1.id = table2.id;
```

Comment: I want Table2 common to Table1

Comment: hey guys can u upvote me so I can ask question again ?

Answer (score 0):

This workaround may solve your problem. First took sub-query as the common Ids and check with WHERE clause:

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.*
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID
WHERE T1.ID IN  (
    SELECT DISTINCT T1.ID
    FROM Table1 TT1
    INNER JOIN Table2 TT2 ON TT2.ID = TT1.ID)
```

Sample execution with given table. I tried in **SSMS** so the syntax may vary.

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (id int, name varchar(20), [address] varchar(20), phone int)

insert into @Table1 (id,name, [address] ,phone)
VALUES
   (1, 'Nirdosh', 'Shrestha',984901),
   (2, 'krishna', 'hora',984902),
   (7, 'birami', 'pokhara',984903)

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (id int, [weight] int, [destination] varchar(20), age int)

insert into @Table2 (id, [weight], destination, age)
VALUES
   (1, 52, 'balkhu' ,32),
   (2, 53, 'hanger' ,35),
   (2, 65, 'fursad' ,35),
   (3, 70, 'Ktm ' ,10)

SELECT T1.*, T2.*
FROM @Table1 T1
INNER JOIN @Table2 T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID
WHERE T1.ID IN  (
    SELECT DISTINCT T1.ID
    FROM @Table1 TT1
    INNER JOIN @Table2 TT2 ON TT2.ID = TT1.ID)
```